# HTTP Status 406 - org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: spring, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While sending request from postman it shows me 
HTTP Status 406 
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
Also on console it print  org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException Exception

error--------->>

```
    13:30:24.143 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.xptraining.controller.CartController@30ed94b8]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    13:30:24.145 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.xptraining.controller.CartController@30ed94b8]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    13:30:24.145 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.xptraining.controller.CartController@30ed94b8]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    13:30:24.146 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
14:39:11.951 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xptraining</groupId>
    <artifactId>xptraining</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql-Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.24</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

controller -------->>>

```
package com.xptraining.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.xptraining.model.Cart;
import com.xptraining.model.Status;
import com.xptraining.services.CartService;

/**
 * The Cart Controller Class
 * 
 * @author Harshad Kenjale
 *
 */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cart")
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    CartService cartServices;

    /**
     * Get All records in Cart
     *  
     * @return All Cart List
     */

  @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Cart> getCart() {

System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@hello i m from list controller@@@@@@@@@@@");

          List<Cart> cartList = null;
        try {
            cartList = cartServices.getCartList();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*String joined = Joiner.on("\t").join(cartList);*/
        return cartList ;
    }
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>xptraining</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

**rest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        ">
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.xptraining" />

<!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management --> 

 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xptraining.repository" />

         <context:annotation-config />

         <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/training" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="xpointers" />
    </bean>         

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:packagesToScan="com.xptraining.model"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
            >
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: You have the dependency for jackson-databind defined twice at your pom, and your are using a different version that the one for jackson core. Remove one of the jackson-databind dependencies and change the version to 2.7.4.

Comment: @alfcope  i changed that but still it showing me same error . Thank You

Comment: Show the configuration, please. Have you registered the jackson message converter? And review your pom, your jpa dependency is duplicated too.

Comment: @alfcope Hello , i removed that duplicate dependency and also added my configuration and updated pom.xml file to the question . Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not registering the annotation driven on your context. Add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your rest.xml file.

[Enabling the MVC Java Config or the MVC XML Namespace](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)

Do not forget to add the mvc namespace at your xml header:

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="...
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

By the way, you are using Spring 4.3 but your namespaces are pointing to 3.0.

Comment: Yes, when defining the schema locations your definitions are like `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` but you are using spring 4.3, so just in case, it should be `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd`